# Wordpress Create Subsite using multisite Using NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, multisite

We have a requirement for creating sub-site and assign admin user for the site and send a mail to the user with credentials.

But all this we want to do from our backend using `PHP` or `NodeJS`.

I have seen about WordPress rest API, but the docs do not provide enough information on how to create a site.

Tired of searching, looking for some better solution.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75839/create-site-programmatically-for-wpmu

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : Well Thank you for your comment, It helped me find more correct answer , `https://github.com/remkade/multisite-json-api`